# Typescript export types for class references

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define an interface that other team members can adhere to when defining a module of code such that some consuming piece of code can make assumptions about a module and any new modules only need to adhere to the interface (more or less) in order to be added to the system.

Let's say for example that I have a directory `Foo` that that exports the following from it's `index.ts`:

```
import * as propertyC from './propertyC'

export const foo:IModule = {
    propertyA: value,
    propertyB: value,
    propertyC
}
```

`propertyC` above imports 1 or more classes. I want to be able to define propertyC as a reference to constructors (not instances) and be able to have the IDE know what the classes are to make life easier. I am able to define `IModule` as:

```
interface IModule {
    propertyA: MyTypeA;
    propertyB: MyTypeB;
    propertyC: {
      [source:string]: typeof MyClass
    };
}
```

However when I want to call `new foo.propertyC.MyClass()` `foo.propertyC` does not know what classes exist at `propertyC`. In my testing this seems like a shortcoming of the index signature that I have defined (which makes sense). I have also played with generics and tried to pass in some type to `IModule` but haven't had any luck.

I'd like to have any consuming code know what classes exists on `propertyC` while also allowing `propertyC` to contain different classes dependant upon what a module exports (but it will always be class constructors).

Is it possible to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can make this work by using `typeof` with the `propertyC` import.

```
import * as propertyC from "./propertyC"

interface IModule {
    propertyA: MyTypeA;
    propertyB: MyTypeB;
    propertyC: typeof propertyC;
}

function test(foo: IModule) {
  new foo.propertyC.MyClass("me")
}
```

for reference:

```
// propertyC.ts
export class MyClass { constructor(public name: string) {} }
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I sent myself down a rabbit hole on this.